# Independent variables not having same meaning for all possible values of the dependent variable.

Tags: r, python, modeling

I have some data describing a particular state (0=healthy, 1=not healthy), with some variables describing theses states. My problem is that some of this variables does not make sense in both state, as for example: is_your_boss_sick_the_day_before_you_got_sick, wont make sense to have on the healthy state. Also for example the type of absence is a variable which doesn't have the exact meaning in the healthy state, as 'short-middle-long term absence period' have a certain meaning, while 'short-middle-long term healthy period' does not really have a meaning (at least not the same).

Hence, I don't think that a model like logistic regression would be a good choice. I can't see the best thing to do in order to understand the significance of these variables in getting sick

I will appreciate any kinds of help,
Thank you very much!!

Comment: `is_your_boss_sick_the_day_before_you_got_sick` seems useless information for your research question. If you had a variable `boss_was_sick` and could lag it, it would be useful. But a predictor that depends on the outcome is not really a predictor.

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you very much for your answer! I totally agree that a predictor depending on the outcome is not really a predictor, and that's why I am still not convinced on any analysis yet. The variable you mentioned is one of the most important for our goal, so unfortunately I will need to find an analysis that allow to use this variable. Basically, with this variable we would like to see if the fact that your boss is sick could makes you more likely to be sick. I hope to be clear enough, but do not hesitate to ask for any clarification! Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: " the fact that your boss is sick could makes you more likely to be sick" You can't get this from your data.

Comment: I don't understand why that must be true?

Comment: The probability that you were sick if you answered that question is 100 %. Since people who didn't get sick didn't answer this question you can't infer the probability of getting sick from it.

Comment: The data analysis should have been decided on *before* the survey was created, not after it has been conducted. Your study is badly designed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not designed any study, just trying to help an industry in understanding the high ratio of absence based on their current variable.  To me the people that did not get sick also answer the question, As I know for each person his day at work and his day sick. So to me we can answer this question, as we have the data...

Comment: "I know for each person his day at work and his day sick" Does that include the bosses? Because then you can create the variable `boss_is_sick` from my first comment and use that,

Comment: Yes I have this data for every person, including boss. 'Boss_is_sick'  variable means 'is you boss sick' but when? at the first date of your absence? meanwhile?

Comment: For example, I could look at the correlation between the boss state time series with each of his employee state time series. This could already give an idea I guess. But I would have like to introduce this into one analysis with all the variables.

Comment: Presumably you have time series of all work days for all employees (including supervisors). Now you can lag the supervisor time series (by one, two, ... days) and use that as a predictor for their subordinates. If you see something interesting there (don't forget plotting), you can get more sophisticated.

Comment: Indeed, I have all the time series. Which type of analysis or you talking about? Sorry I don't understand, would be very nice to have more details if possible

Comment: Consider getting a subcontractor for the analysis. I don't have time to help you more (especially if you get a nice profit and I don't).

Comment: Thanks for your help then. Just in case, I dont get any profit, I only get experience, which is a lot already.

Comment: Also, your idea of laging, if I understood correctly, is exactly what I described in my question, saying that to me this is false. As this variable wont have any sence for the 'healthy' state.

Comment: You don't understand the what lagging a time series means. If I have 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0  for the subordinate then I can lag it by -1 --> 0, 1, 0, 0, NA. Now I have the supervisor 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0. Clearly, the employee was healthy when the supervisor was and had been sick and sick when the supervisor was and had been healthy. So there is a "sense" for the healthy state. If you had one employee and one supervisor you would look into cross-correlations, but since you have more then one employee per supervisor and many supervisors you need some kind of regression analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Roland. To me a lag of a time series at time t is its previous element (lag one). Hence, I still understand the same thing, that you suggest to introduce the previous (lag 1) state of the boss in the regression.

Comment: (continuing my last comment: ...which is exactly: is your boss sick the day before'). Perhaps a variable could then be: 'the day before your current state, was your boss of the same state as you are now'... . Still I am not convinced of regression for this problem... we have time varying variables and I feel I am loosing a lot of informations in any analysis that I am thinking of :(. In any case thank you for your time Roland!